# Why are methods -- and - deprecated for List?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

The `--` and `-` operators/methods on List are deprecated.

For `--`, we get: "deprecated: use `list1 filterNot (list2 contains)` instead"

The suggested use is verbose. Why deprecate the operators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason I found is that `--` is really a difference operator that logically applies to `Set`, rather than to `List`. This is the reason `--` is not deprecated on `Set`.

For `List`, a filter operation makes more sense. So it may be simply be for logical consistency.

Comment: True enough. One might also consider the distinction between `++` and `--`. It would be reasonable to expect one to be the inverse of the other, but that's not the case.

Comment: @Daniel - I would have preferred that `--` be fixed to be the inverse of `++`, even though it's either `O(n^2)` or requires the building of a `O(n)`-sized data structure.

Comment: @Rex `@migration` did not exist at the time this choice was made. I think this is one deprecation that would have been a migration warning had it existed when the decision to deprecate was made.